# Code for Peres gate in overleaf

Tags: circuitikz, qcircuit

[image]

How do write the code in overleaf for perez gate (*the graphical notation*).
I'm having trouble finding the **"circle + dot" notation(B line)** online.

Comment: BTW, if my answer helped you, it'd be nice if you could accept it by clicking on the checkmark symbol.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[anchor=east] {A} -- +(2,0) node[anchor=west] {P};
\draw (0,-1) node[anchor=east] {B} -- +(2,0) node[anchor=west] {Q};
\draw (0,-2) node[anchor=east] {C} -- +(2,0) node[anchor=west] {R};
\draw[fill] (1,0) circle[radius=0.125];
\draw[fill] (1,-1) circle[radius=0.125];
\draw (1,-1) circle[radius=0.175];
\draw (1,-2) circle[radius=0.175];
\draw (1,0) -- +(0,-2.175);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

If the wires are not supposed to "cross" behind the dot, you can reorder the drawing commands some and "paint over" with a filled white circle, like so:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[anchor=east] {A} -- +(2,0) node[anchor=west] {P};
\draw (0,-1) node[anchor=east] {B} -- +(2,0) node[anchor=west] {Q};
\draw (0,-2) node[anchor=east] {C} -- +(2,0) node[anchor=west] {R};
\draw (1,0) -- +(0,-2.175);
\draw[fill] (1,0) circle[radius=0.125];
\draw[fill=white] (1,-1) circle[radius=0.175];
\draw[fill] (1,-1) circle[radius=0.125];
\draw (1,-1) circle[radius=0.175];
\draw (1,-2) circle[radius=0.175];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

In general, BTW, `circuitikz` is an excellent package for all sorts of circuit-related things, and I recommend checking it out; it's also under active development, and if you find that something is missing and suggest that it be added, I believe chances are good that it will. In addition there's also the `quantikz` package. I have little personal experience with either of these, however.

Comment: (thanks @chsk for the nice words for `circuitikz`). I would use this solution --- the connection dots of circuitikz are smaller and really do not find this usage. You can define three `.../.style` for the three kind of connections and then use them in conjunction with `circuitikz`.